# How to design basic physics and movement behavior for 2D platformer?

Tags: 2d, physics, platformer

I want to make a simple 2D platformer.

I know some basic 2D physics and how to implement them in a game. How to make a character jump, accelerate, decelerate, etc.

But I have no idea how to actually make a 2D platformer, regarding the character's movement.

For example, I'm not sure how to implement:

1. The character stops moving when running into a wall, but can still move in the opposite direction.
2. Same for ceiling and floor, while taking gravity, acceleration, etc into account.
3. Similar basic physics and behavior related things.
4. Make all of this "natural" in how it's designed. This isn't what I mean:

   ```
   if (character touches ceiling) {fall}
   ```

   but this is what I mean:

   ```
   if (character touches object) {move accordingly}
   ```

It's a little hard for me to explain what I'm looking for, but I hope you understand.

If you could point me to some good source or tutorial on the subject, that would be great. Or explain these basic fundamental mechanisms yourself. Thanks.

(Without an engine)

Comment: The [n+ tutorials](http://www.metanetsoftware.com/technique.html) (links on the RHS) are a very good introduction to 2D platforming physics.

Just so you're aware, you have long and treacherous road ahead of you. If your primary interest is in writing the physics engine then this is the way to go, but if your primary interest is in making a game, then I suggest you take a close look at all the 2d engines available before you decide to write this yourself.

Comment: I remember a tutorial doing that with raycast in Unity, but I can't find it.

Answer (score 0):

You are asking about *collision detection*.  Make certain you try learning 2D first, and there are plenty of youtube and wiki tutorials for you to find.

As an example, imagine Mario is represented by a rectangle with position and size.  A fireball can also be represented by a point.  Then you can check each frame like this:

```
if(fireball.x > mario.x  && fireball.x < mario.x + mario.width &&
    fireball.y > mario.y && fireball.y < mario.y + mario.height){
   //The fireball is inside Mario's bounds! Ohhh nooooo!
}
```

There are lots of types of collision detection, so if you want to keep it simple, make everything the same shape (usually rectangles or circles). Have fun!

Answer (score 0):

In this answer I assume you are using C++ Object Oriented Programming. If you are using another language, then hopefully you are still able to make use of my answer.

1. Do what drumbumLOLcatz said, and do collision detecting. [This link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Games/Techniques/2D_collision_detection) has some good examples in JavaScript, which is easy enough to understand and convert to any other language. And a quick Google search should bring up plenty of pages describing in depth collision detecting and how to implement it.
2. Do the same as 1
3. If your trying to set up a physics system that uses Gravity and acceleration, I recommend using a 2d Vector:

   ```
   struct Vector2D {
       float x;
       float y;
   }
   ```

   A Vector can be used to represent a Location and Velocity (along with many other things). To set up a simple physics system you have a Vector for Position `Vector2D Position = { 0, 0 };`. Then you have a Vector represent Velocity `Vector2D Velocity = { 1, 1 };`, with each value hold the rate of change for that axis, and each time you update your objects add the Velocity Vector to the Position Vector, causing your object to move based off of velocity:

   ```
   Position.x += Velocity.x;  // Increase the X position by the X velocity
   Position.y += Velocity.y;  // Increase the Y position by the Y velocity
   ```

   To add gravity, simply take a Gravity Vector `Vector2 Gravity = { 0, 9.8 };` and add it to the Velocity Vector, increasing your fall speed.
4. As for making it natural? Well... You closest you could get visually to:

   ```
   if (character touches object) {move accordingly}
   ```

   Would be to create a method in your Character class that will check for collision with a given object.

   ```
   if (character.touches(object)) {move accordingly}
   ```

   The .touches() method should look something like drumbumLOLcatz's example. However, in that example, you can only check if they are touching. You wouldn't be able to tell which object is on which side of the  other, which is on top, etc. That is fine for the case of a fireball, but when a player hits a block, you need to know what side it was on. What you might want to do is have the `touches()` method return a number, indicating what side the player is on. You could then have a switch to handle each direction.

   ```
   switch character.touches(object)
   {
   case 1:  // Character is on top
       { move accordingly }
   case 2:  // Character is on left
       { move accordingly }
   ...
   {
   ```

   In that way, you would be able to tell what side the character is on the object. I hope this was of some help to you.